# I'm not able to use my C/C++ compiler on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, mingw

I followed the gcc compiler installation tutorial for windows from the vscode website: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

And the bin folder (C:\msys64\mingw64\bin) is empty, so i'm not able to run the "g++ --version" by adding this path to the Windows path environment variable.

My alternative to it was to use the codeblocks compiler to run my code in vscode, by adding this path: (C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin) to the "path" selection in the windows environment variables.

I want to make the MSYS2 compiler work properly in my vscode.

Hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSYS2 comes with a package manager `pacman` that you should use to install any components you need.

In your case, open the MSYS2 shell (by running `mingw64.exe`) and run the following commands:

```bash
pacman -Syu --noconfirm 
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

The first command will tell the package manager to update it's database, the second command will get the MinGW-w64 64-bit GCC compiler.

If you don't really need MSYS2 (e.g. because you dan't plan to use the MSYS2 shell) you could also consider getting a standalone MinGW-w64 build from https://winlibs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here I faced a same issue I have solved it by doing this:

FolderPath:

> C:\Softwares\msys2\ucrt64\bin

paste msys2 ucrt64/bin in the VSCODE editSetting.Json

> {
> "workbench.colorTheme": "Solarized Dark",
> "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "c:\Softwares\msys2\ucrt64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe"
> }